# Write Algorithm for changing non-directional graph to directional

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I need help to solve this question :

you have undirected graph G=(V,E) you want to write an algorithm  to adjust all
One of the edges, so that in the directed graph obtained, he number of incoming edges into the node be always greater than zero.
for all edge {u,v} ∈ E you should chose one direction (u,v) or (v,u).
When the answer is positive, the algorithm must return the intention of the edges - which fulfills the requirement

Comment: what is the definition of "peak level"? it doesn't even appear in the search results

Comment: Sorry i mean the number of nodes entrance points should be always greater than 0

Comment: you probably mean the number of incoming edges into the node?

Comment: yes this is what i mean

Comment: so obviously that sort of adjustment is not always possible, for example if there are only two nodes and one edge between them

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out, this problem clearly does not always have a solution. Since every vertex must have at least one incoming edge, if we have E < V, the problem is impossible.

So, let's assume that we have E >= V. Here is one way to approach the algorithm: First, count the number of edges attached to each vertex in O(E) time. Note, my solution assumes appropriate storage like an adjacency list. Can you see why an adjacency matrix would have a worse complexity?

Second, we will make a binary minheap of the vertices, according to their corresponding edge count, in O(V). Some intuition: if we have a vertex with only one edge, we must convert that into an incoming edge! When we assign the direction of that edge, we need to update the edge count of the vertex on the other side. If that other vertex goes from 2 edges to 1, we now are forced to assign the direction of its one edge left. Visually:

1 - 2 - 1

Arbitrarily choose a 1 edge count to make directed

1 - 2 -> 0

2 just lost an edge, so update to 1!

1 - 1 -> 0

Since it only has 1 edge now, convert its edge to be incoming!

0 -> 0 -> 0

Obviously this graph doesn't work since V > E, but you get the idea.

So, V times, we extract the minimum from the heap and fix in O(logV). Each time, decrement the edge count of the neighbor. Assuming the adjacency list, we can find a neighbor (first element) and update the count in O(1), and we can fix the heap again in O(logV). Overall, this step takes O(V logV).

Note, if all of our remaining vertices have more than one possible edge, this approach will arbitrarily select one of the vertices with a smallest edge count and arbitrarily select one of its edges. I will let you think about why this works (or try to provide a counter-example if you think it doesn't!) Finally, if E > V, then when we finish, there may be extra unnecessary edges left over. In O(E) time, we can arbitrarily assign directions to those edges.

Overall, we are looking at V + V*logV + E aka O(E + VlogV). Hope this helps!